# Is it legal for an EU-based online retailer to geoblock non-EU/EEA customers?

Tags: internet, european-union, commerce

The company I work for (based in Germany) offers online courses.

The company would like to block users from non-EU/EEA countries (because of taxation complexity when we take payments from outside EU/EAA).

Regulation (EU) 2018/302 prohibits geo-blocking **within** the EU/EEA (so a German online trader cannot block a customer residing in Spain).

[https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32018R0302#:~:text=Regulation%20(EU)%202018%2F302,2006%2F2004%20and%20(EU)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32018R0302#:%7E:text=Regulation%20(EU)%202018%2F302,2006%2F2004%20and%20(EU))

However, I have not been able to find information on whether it would be legal for an EU online trader to geo-block **non-EU/EEA** customers (from the United States, Russia etc).

Comment: Is there a reason your company cannot consult a legal professional about this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it is illegal? In principle everything not prohibited is legal.